# Throw T-SQL exception from CLR

Tags: .net, t-sql, clr

I have a lot of MSSQL scripts using CLR procedure in them. .NET code handles SQL exceptions and notifies them, if they bypass SQL error handling. Problem is, if CLR throws exception which does not get handled, SLQ script writes it in Message window and continues execution of script like nothing had happened. How can I throw "deadly" T-SQL exception from CLR?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is desirable to throw a "deadly" exception. Instead, you should TSQL decide whether it is right to quit. You will often need to release resources such as application locks.

Here's the docs on exception handling in TSQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

If you want to just die on any exception, wrap your existing code in an empty try catch block:

```
BEGIN TRY
  existing statements
END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH;
```

Comment: "I have a lot of MSSQL scripts using CLR procedure in them." means that I dont want to go through each of them and edit them. CLR procedure resides in multiple systems and that would be a drag. I found a better solution.

Comment: But since I dont want to accept my own solution and this also would work. I will accept this one.

Answer (score 1):

For this particular case, where I have a multiple scripts using CLR procedure, Its not the best solution to go through each of the scripts and edit them, since It could invite unpredictable behavior. I found these three solutions useful.

I. `set xact_abort on` makes CLR to stop and rollback current transaction on error. There are multiple variations how to use it. (Before each call or for whole database) This was not the best solution either, since I dont want to edit all occurrences of procedure and seting xact_abort on whole database could do something unpredictable.

II. Rename existing CLR procedure. Create new procedure with same parameters and name as CLR procedure before it was renamed. Put this code in new procedure call.

```
set xact_abort on
exec renamed_clr_procedure @arg1=v1, @arg2=v2, ...
set xact_abort off
```

Also there could be check if the xact_abort isnt already set in the first place. Then we should only call renamed_clr_procedure.

III. Since I noticed, that all SQL procedure (containing CLR procedure) calls come from one place, before I executed procedure I called `set xact_abort on` before procedure and `set xact_abort off` after procedure.